# How to search for a field with a value deep in BSON Document in Java

Tags: java, bson, bsondocument

Given I have this sample BSON Document which I retrieved from Mongo DB.

```
{
    "field1": "text1",
    "field2": {
        "field2Sub1": "text2"
    },
    "field3" : [
        {
            "field3Sub1": "text3",
            "field3Sub2": "text4"
        },
        {
            "field3Sub1": "text5",
            "field3Sub2": "text6"
        }
    ],
    "field4": {
        "field4Sub1": "text7",
        "field4Sub2" : [
             {
                 "field4Sub2Sub1": "text8",
                 "field4Sub2Sub2": "text9"
            },
            {
                 "field4Sub2Sub1": "text10",
                 "field4Sub2Sub2": "text11"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In Mongo DB if I want to search for a document that has a field of `field4Sub2Sub2` that contains the value `"text11"`.

I can just do this kind of search query:

```
{"field4.field4Sub2.field4Sub2Sub2": "text11"}
```

Alternatively, I can also search a document that has a field of `field3Sub1` that contains the value `text3` with this kind of search:

```
{"field3.field3Sub1": "text11"}
```

Given the object above, I converted this to a Java BSON Document.
And, I would like to ask if there is a way in Java or a Java Library that can search through the internals of Document and give me the value of a particular field.

Using a dot annotated search string e.g.
`"field3[0].field3Sub1"`
or
`"field4.field4Sub1"`
or
`"field4.field4Sub2[1].field4Sub2Sub2"`

which will be returning the following values correspondingly:

```
text3
text7
text11
```

Thanks